# Is there a nice(r) way to have default values in objects

Tags: python-3.x, properties, member

What I'm aiming at is having a object in python3 behaving as normal with regards to attribute access, except that if an attribute is not available through the normal lookup it should fetch/calculate the value in some other way.

I know that one **could** solve the problem by defining the `__getattr__` method:

```
 def __getattr__(self, key):
     if key == 'foo':
         return calculate_default_foo()
     elif key == 'bar':
         return getattr(dfltobj, 'bar')
     elif key == 'frob':
         return 42
     raise AttributeError
```

but that feels so python2 so I wonder if there's a more elegant way to do this in python3. Just defining `property`s don't work that well since they completely override accesses to that attribute, but otherwise that would be a nice approach if it had worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way around it, but there is a nice(r) way of modifying `__getattr__`:

```
def __getattr__(self, item):
    if item == "foo" and not self.foo:
        return calculate_default()
    return self.__getattribute__(foo)
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question a bit. The intention is that `foo.attr2` should yield a default value (which may need to be calculated on the fly).

Comment: My bad! I think I got it now .-.